# #DocuSign API: Tab label update from API

Tags: tags, docusignapi

We are trying to fetch the tab labels of a template uisng API call and succesfull to get that, but the our requirement is to update the tab label name using API.

Example:
During the tab label creation my DocuSign admin mentioned first Name as FirstNAMe in label but for mapping label name is FirtsName.

we can login and search the template and correct the tab label name there but we nee here to update using API call.

Please if someone can suggest Here....

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify existing recipient tabs through the DocuSign REST API.  The API Documentation describes call you need to make in detail (page 198):

[Modify Recipient Tabs](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=198)

URL:

`/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`

Formats:

`XML, JSON`

HTTP Method:

`PUT`

Parameters:

`tabId` (required)

**Example Request:**

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/
recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
X-DocuSign-Authentication: 
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "approveTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "titleTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }],
    "signHereTabs":[{
        <Tab information removed>
    }]
}
```